# How to write a For Loop for all powers of 2 from 1 to 1 million Python

Tags: python, for-loop

The output should look like this: 1,2,4,8,16,32, etc all the way to 1 million. My code right now is :

```py
for i in range(1, 1000000, i**2):
    print(i)
```

However, I keep getting errors.

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: Powers of 2 are not squares. Powers of 2 are 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. Squares are 1, 4, 9, 16, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given a hint that the numbers are less than 20, so no need to have an infinite loop. Just run a loop 20 times.

```
for i in range(20):
    print(2**i) # from 1 till 524288
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 1
for i in range(1,1000000):
    if i**2>100000:
        break
    print(i**2)
```

If you do the squaring in the print statement and add a conditional break statement when the square of i is greater than 1 million it will work

Answer (score 2):

Using a generator is a clean, reusable and efficient way of expressing your intent:

```
def powers_of(x, max):
    i = 0
    while x**i < max:
        yield x**i
        i = i + 1

for i in powers_of(2, 1000000):
    print(i)
```

(EDIT: adapted for "powers_of" because you were initially asked for "squares")

Answer (score 0):

You need to square it while printing it. So your program should be:

```py
import itertools

for i in itertools.count():
    if 2 ** i < 1000000:
        print(2 ** i)
```

Comment: That crashes my system, it just multiples forever.

Comment: @SophiaSimpson It does not run forever. It runs 1,000,000 times

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Probably Sophia meant that it should print numbers up to 1 million in size.

Comment: @Arty Edited the answer.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I think number 1 should be printed too, so you need to do just `print(i ** 2)`. And `while i ** 2 < 1000000`.

Comment: @Arty Ok. Done that as well. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes.